# How to include $sum field for each existing field in a document with aggregate?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have this document.

```
{
"_id": "1",
"name": "KP",
"points": 20
},
{
"_id": "2",
"name": "Josh",
"points: 30
}, 
{
"_id": "3",
"name": "Angelo",
"points": 50
}
```

How do I get the sum of all fields (should be 100) and then add them on each document?

```
{
"_id": "1",
"name": "KP",
"points": 20,
"total": 100
},
{
"_id": "2",
"name": "Josh",
"points": 30,
"total": 100
}, 
{
"_id": "3",
"name": "Angelo",
"points": 50,
"total": 100
}
```

I need this so I could divide and multiply later on because my plan really is to add a percent field, like a share on the total points (i.e. for 50 pts, (50 / 100) * 100 = 50%. Like this:

```
{
"_id": "1",
"name": "KP",
"points": 20,
"percentage": 20
},
{
"_id": "2",
"name": "Josh",
"points": 30,
"total": 30
}, 
{
"_id": "3",
"name": "Angelo",
"points": 50,
"percentage": 50
}
```

So far I have this which is incorrect:

```
db.users.aggregate({$match:{}}, {$project: {_id: 1, name: 1, points: "$points"}}, {$group: {_id: "$name", total: {$sum: "$points"}}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$setWindowFields` to compute the total with `"partitionBy": null`. Then use `$divide` and `$multiply` to compute the percentage.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$setWindowFields": {
      "output": {
        "total": {
          "$sum": "$points"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      percentage: {
        "$multiply": [
          {
            "$divide": [
              "$points",
              "$total"
            ]
          },
          100
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/twziOkU_rHe)

Comment: got it. this is perfect. just a question. what does partitionby null means?

Comment: @user874737 oh you don't actually need that. Just updated the answer. You can think of that like the grouping. "partitionBy": null means a unconditional grouping for all documents.

Comment: i see, so removing it is the same as null. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For Your script you must edit the variable

It would look like this:

```
db.users.aggregate({$match:{}}, {$project: {_id: 1, discordId: 1nil, currency: "$currency"}}, {$group: {#id: "$discordId", total: {$um: "$currency"}}})
```

With my experience this should work in a normal app.
What i did was Pick the #Id to a number and turned the currency to a nil.